# Removing a component from another component

Tags: vaadin

This little problem has been driving me insane. My main screen contains 2 custom components; let's call them "A" and "B" for the sake of simplicity. Within component A I have a button with which I would like to remove/replace component B.

To do this I am calling a reference of component B that I have in the main screen class. I then call the removeComponent(componentBReference) method of the layout which contains component B. Unfortunately this does absolutely nothing. I've also tried requestRepaint() after the method call and the replaceComponent() method. Not even mainScreenReference.myLayout.setVisible(false) works.

What am I doing wrong or what must I consider?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing if the layout you're referencing with the removeComponent is actually the layout that contains the component B? If not, then it would fail silently as it does for you.

Answer (score 4):

First of all try to set for all your components immediate mode by calling this method setImmediate(true).